# SonarQube won't analyze C# project named Test*

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have a project called TestCommander, it is not a test project but instead a product that helps people within the organization to write integration tests easier.

Obviously I want to analyze this C# code. But as it is now it seem to be ignored by SonarQube since it is named Test*, correctly assessed?

Structure is like this:

```
CompanyName.TestCommander
    - Commands
        - HttpGetCommand.cs
        - ...
    - TestScanner.cs
    - TestRunner.cs
    - CompanyName.TestCommander.csproj
```

What I have done:

- Tried Source Inclusion: **/*.cs
- Tried Test Inclusion: **/*.cs
- Both at the same time.
- More specific pointing out the exact files I wanted to include

None of these have worked.

My setup:
Internal SonarQube 6.7
Automated build in TFS 2017.3 with the VSTS task versioned 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects that have "Test" in their name are considered test projects (e.g. containing only tests) and their analysis results are not pushed to SonarQube. You could try adding `/d:sonar.msbuild.testProjectPattern=<pattern>` to the list of the arguments to `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin`, or in your case to `Advanced / Additional Settings`, where `<pattern>` is a .NET regex pattern that will match your test projects' names, but not your main project.

We will change this behavior in the near future, because we would like to push analysis results of tests to SonarQube, but still, by default projects with `Test` in their name will most probably be considered as test projects and some rules will behave differently.

Comment: Worked. Didn't consider that the change was needed to be done on the MSBuild side. Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @Nings yes, but it is rather difficult to find and recognize it is related to the same problem... https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Miscellaneous+Advanced+Usages

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSource - Have you added analysis for test projects? because when I run SonarQube on a test project I get no analysis at all...